# What does Mandrill do with attachments in test mode?

Tags: mandrill

I am porting a client's website away from using the servers sendmail to using Mandrill. Creating a test API key is great for testing the code/process on a dev version of the site, but is there a way I can test that the attachments are working within this test mode?

Answer (score 14):

You can see your attachments in your API Logs (cover the last 100 API calls) in test mode

Comment: For those who missed it, you need to scroll down to see the last 100 **successful** calls.

Comment: Any idea on how you can get the attachment and look at the file?

Comment: Settings > API Logs (https://mandrillapp.com/settings/api) is where you can view the API Logs

Comment: This answer is the only way to find out in sandbox mode if the attachments are working or not.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I experienced last week, there's no option to preview an attachment in test mode. Actually I wasn't able to do it even with production keys which is quite surprising if I'm not missing something.

All I can see in the API logs is the email, but at least for me, there is no option to preview the attachment.